# Sticky Sidebar not Sticking

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I am trying to make a sticky sidebar that stops at the bottom of a webpage's header image, but I'm unable to get it to work. I've recreated the issue in the snippet below and in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bubinga_/t23f8r10/8/) which might be easier to look at/test in.

The sidebar is looking how I want it, but when I scroll down it doesn't halt at the top of the page

```css
.about {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

h4 {
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
}

.about-header-image {
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-color: #919191;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 3rem !important;
  padding-bottom: 2rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 42px !important;
}

.nav-with-bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav-with-bar.aboutnav {
  position: sticky;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  bottom: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 150px;
}

.nav-with-bar h5 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-with-bar .nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-with-bar .nav-link.active {
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}

.nav-with-bar a {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.nav-with-bar a:hover {
  color: #064579;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="content">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 container-fluid pl-2">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="/Index">
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;" class="d-inline-block">Website</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="about-header-image" style="background-image: url(Assets/Wallpaper.jpg) !important;">
    <div class="my-auto text-center">
      <h1 style="font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif; font-size: 4em;" class="text-white d-inline-block">
        Website Name
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="h-100">
    <div class="nav-with-bar aboutnav d-md-inline-block offset-1 col-2 d-none mr-3">
      <h5>About Us</h5>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#purpose" class="nav-link">Purpose</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#founding" class="nav-link">Founding</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#future" class="nav-link">Future</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#contributors" class="nav-link">Contributors</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 d-inline-block about">
      <div id="purpose" style="font-size: x-large;">
        <h4 class="mb-0">Filler Text</h4>
        <hr class="nogap">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
          ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
          ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
          mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want it to disappear once the user scrolls past the 'Website Name' part? Is that possible with only CSS?

Comment: I want it to stick to the navbar so when the user is at the bottom of the page they can still see the navigation menu. I know it is possible because I had it working a month or so ago, but I broke it recently and can't figure out how to get it back

Comment: I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing, [this](https://imgur.com/a/SsdB7zX) is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have marked all my edits in css.

```css
.about {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

h4 {
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
}

.h-100 {
    display: flex; /*add this it*/
}

.about-header-image {
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-color: #919191;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 3rem !important;
  padding-bottom: 2rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 42px !important;
}

.nav-with-bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav-with-bar.aboutnav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 81px; /*add this it*/
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  bottom: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 150px;
  
  display: flex!important; /*add this it*/
  flex-direction: column; /*add this it*/
  height: 100%; /*add this it*/
}

.nav-with-bar h5 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-with-bar .nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-with-bar .nav-link.active {
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}

.nav-with-bar a {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.nav-with-bar a:hover {
  color: #064579;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="content">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 container-fluid pl-2">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="/Index">
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;" class="d-inline-block">Website</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="about-header-image" style="background-image: url(Assets/Wallpaper.jpg) !important;">
    <div class="my-auto text-center">
      <h1 style="font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif; font-size: 4em;" class="text-white d-inline-block">
        Website Name
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="h-100">
    <div class="nav-with-bar aboutnav d-md-inline-block offset-1 col-2 d-none mr-3">
      <h5>About Us</h5>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#purpose" class="nav-link">Purpose</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#founding" class="nav-link">Founding</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#future" class="nav-link">Future</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#contributors" class="nav-link">Contributors</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="/About#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 d-inline-block about">
      <div id="purpose" style="font-size: x-large;">
        <h4 class="mb-0">Filler Text</h4>
        <hr class="nogap">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
          ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
          ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
          mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```